# using / in a sed search/replacement string

Tags: bash, sed, grep

This is probably something stupid simple, but I've been looking around for the past 3 hours trying to figure out a solution.  I need to insert a word (defined by a variable "$t") into a file (/etc/reliance.env) BEFORE another word that happens to have a "/" in it. (Let's say "/custom.")

My current solution involves replacing /custom with $t /custom.  The problem being that sed doesn't seem to like using the character "/".  I'm sure there's a more effective solution anyway.  Any insight? Thanks in advance!

```
     if grep "/custom" /etc/reliance.env; then
        sed -i 's/"/custom/"/"$t /custom/"/g' reliance.env
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just about any character as the delimiter in an `s///` command. If you need slashes in your pattern or replacement just use something else.

```
sed -i "s,/custom,$t &,g" reliance.env
```

(I used `&` in the replacement which means "the entire match" to avoid needing to type it out again.)

You also need double quotes (instead of single quotes) if you want the shell to expand the `$t` variable. If not then single quotes are what you wanted.

Unless your file is very large or you need to not modify it at all unless the contents are there running `grep` first is probably not necessary (and you should definitely tell `grep` to stop on the first match with `-m 1` since that's alll you care about and silence the output from `grep` with `-q`).

Answer (score 0):

escape the character:

```
sed -i "s/\/custom/\$t \custom/g/" reliance.env
```

EDIT: Also, grepping through the file is not substantially faster than running `sed` on it, so just skip the `if grep ...`, and just do your `sed`ing.